# How to prevent generation of the same OTPs in MVC 2FA

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

MVC 2FA sometimes generates the same OTP (I have set to 6 numericals) and when you generate multiple OTPs, one can use the previous OTP.
Is there a way to generate unique OTPs and disable the previous generated OTP?

```
 string code = await UserManager.GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(user.Id, provider);
```

This is the time set before the OTP expires

```
app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
```

Comment: You should not allow user to regenerate OTP for certain period of time, let say 10 seconds, once the OTP is generated. That will help you to create unique OTP. Also use back end to track the OTP expiration instead of cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OTP are time based and not recorded anywhere. If you generate 2 OTPs within a short period of time, you'll get identical strings. And this is how algorithm is working and there is no *easy* way around it.

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled across this post today and found a simple solution to the problem.

https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/asp-net-core-identity-token-providers

This link describes the fact that the SecurityTokenStamp is used in the verification process.  So for me it was a simple matter of updating it each time I sent out an SMS token for the user.  Effectively invalidating the original one.

```
  if(await userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user.Id) != IdentityResult.Success)
        {
            // https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/asp-net-core-identity-token-providers
            // we update it to effectively reset all the token validation stuff
            return IdentityResult.Failed("failed to update the security stamp");
        }

        // Send token - this may throw but thats ok as we just rollback
        string code = await userManager.GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(user.Id, "twilio");
        await userManager.SmsService.SendAsync(new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityMessage
        {
            Destination = user.UserName,
            Body = "Your security code is: " + code
        });
```

Comment: Look like a good solution. Did you experienced any side affects implementing this approach?

Answer (score 2):

The OTP which is generating via `UserManager.GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync` is not a One Time Password even though we called it OTP. It is a TOTP ( Time based one time password).
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-Time_Password

Therefore in a particular time period the generated passwords can be slimier.
For SMS and Email I have noticed that the time period is around 90 seconds. That means within 90 seconds it generates the same password.

For authenticator app also there is this default time period.

By doing lot of researches around this, What I have noticed is, to change this default time period we need to create a custom 2FA token provider.